# Intuition behind modeling quantum impurities as two-level systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body

I've been trying to get a basic understanding of quantum impurity problems, starting with the [Anderson model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_impurity_model).  The Wikipedia article (along with some [review](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3474) [articles](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.68.13)) seems to explain the simplest version of it with two-level terms without telling me why one should keep track of only the two lowest energy states of the impurity, when the second excited state could exist and also be close to the first depending on the what the impurity is.  (they don't always seem to be magnetic)

I see mentions of valence vs. conduction bands, 0 vs. 1 occupancy at the lattice site, or spin up vs. down, but none of them seems clearly explained.

Can anyone enlighten me on this?  Thanks!

Comment: This is similar to the one-band Hubbard model. The two levels are degenerate as NONINTERACTING single-particle energy levels (both have $\epsilon$). It is because of e-e INTERACTION that a second occupied state has a higher energy $U+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I read some more papers on the topic and saw that it is about occupancy as you say.  If you copy+paste your comment above as a full answer below, I will select it.  Otherwise, I'll try to write up a more detailed explanation (answering own question) some weeks later ...

Comment: Sure. You can write it down yourself so it can benefit others.